# Need to get .obj file names of Executable(which one is crrently executing) at runtime programatically in VC++?

Tags: file, visual-c++, reverse-engineering, .obj

Suppose I have a VC++ project containing number of Source (.cpp) files (e.g. 5), it will generate 5 .obj files (corresponding to my .cpp files not all kernel and OS layers including .obj files).

My project includes xyz_1.cpp, xyz_2.cpp, xyz_3.cpp, xyz_4.cpp, and will corresponds with 4 respective .objs files.

How can I get the names of these 4 .obj files at runtime? On runtime I need to check how many obj files there are and their names.

I don't need all kernel or OS layer .obj's, I only need .obj's of my .cpp's.

Regards,

Usman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.obj` file names are not standard. some compilers hay create ones that correspond to the .cpp files, others may create ones with random names (VC actually does that when configured with link time code generation) while others may skip this stage completely.

So there is no well defined answer to your question. it is compiler and compilation flags dependent.

Furthermore, there is no way to get this information that I know of.

Comment: Actually I am using Dumpbin SDK for getting information from pdb or Exe. It gives me every function signature and symbolic info even which I dont want. Suppose I have 3 funcs in one Exe, I only need these 3 funcs signatures not everything starting from User layer ends up to KERNEL level all functions and OS functions. it gives EVERY THING STARTING FROM FUNCTIONS defined in that xyz.cpp and BACKTRACK TO KERNEL EVEN OS LEVEL LAYER.... I dont need all those, I only need functions info regarding defined in my .cpp's or .h's

Comment: U mean u could'nt got What I need ...?

Comment: Suppose i have xyz.cpp. It contains two funcs i.e

int func1(int,int,float) and int func2(int,float,double)

I just need these 2 after using dia2dump sdk. But it gives me EVERYTHING ,ever func even which I dont want. i.e  _initp_misc_rand_s(__initp_misc_rand_s) , _VEC_memcpy(__VEC_memcpy) , __updatetmbcinfo(___updatetmbcinfo) and blah blah blah sky is the limit , 1000's of functions of similar kind, WHICH I DONT NEED..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use Microsoft's [dbghelp.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309(v=VS.85).aspx) library and their [Debug Interface Access SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx).

Comment: I am using Debug Interface Access SDK. That is dia2dump SDK. But it gives me EVERY SYMBOL INFO from user level to KERNEL Level. I dont need EVERY function info. I only need those functions WHICH WEERE DEFINED UNDER MY CPP's(e.g i defined xyz.cpp and its having single function int func_01(int,int) I only need this signature THAT'S IT!!)  I DONT NEED kernel imports, ALL COMPILANDS and EVERY MODULE participating in EXE...